# Why does internal energy depend only on a set of two state variables?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

Why is the internal energy dependent only on two states variables such as $U(S,V)$? Why not on four or five say like $U(P,V,S)$?

I know that using the  equation of state one can reduce the number of variables by one, but that doesn't answer why does internal energy and other thermodynamics potentials depend only on two states variables .

Could anyone explain that.

Answer (score 1):

The internal energy of a system can be changed by heating it, doing work on it, and adding matter to it. These correspond to a shift in entropy $S$, volume $V$ (if only pressure–volume work is considered), and amount $N$.

Thus, the internal energy depends on two variables ($S$ and $N$) plus a variable for each type of work one is considering (e.g., $V$).

For a closed system that can only expand or contract, this corresponds to the two state variables you asked about: $S$ and $V$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by Chemomechanics, I just wanted to add some detail. In general work can be done on a system by jdX where j is a "generalized force" and X is a "generalized displacement". Note the parallel to the work done by a force (W = change in energy = integral of fdx) So one example would be -pdV where the pressure is a "force" and the volume is its conjugate "displacement. If your system lends itself to magnetic work, then work can be done by HdM. For more info, check these lecture notes https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-333-statistical-mechanics-i-statistical-mechanics-of-particles-fall-2013/resources/mit8_333f13_lec1/ around equation I.13